# How do I add Value of cell plus string

Tags: excel

I have a huge list of products in excel and im making a template that will change multiple cells. the plan is that whatever i have in the title it will change all the corresponding cells below, is there a formula that i can copy so it would be like

```
=A1 plus string -2.0m X 4m (6' 6" X 13' 1")

Title: CARPET1

CARPET1-2.0M X 4M (6' 6" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-2.5M X 4M (8' 2" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-3.0M X 4M (9' 10" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-3.5M X 4M (11' 5" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-4.0M X 4M (13' 1" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-4.5M X 4M (14' 9" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-5.0M X 4M (16' 4" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-5.5M X 4M (18' 0" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-6.0M X 4M (19' 8" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-6.5M X 4M (21' 3" X 13' 1")
CARPET1-7.0M X 4M 22' 11" X 13' 1")
```

then I can copy it all the way down so when I change the title it automatically changes the rest any ideas?

Comment: So basically you want to make a formula that will results with something like: `value of A1 *and* something you want to show`, am I right? In that case you can write a simple formula: `=A1 & "string you want to add"`. Just remember to use quote for your string value.

Comment: yes exactly problem is is that its having issues with the "" which is in my string so it would be =A1 & -2.0 X 4M (6' 6" X13' 1")

Comment: Captain, showed you how to do it. Basically in this case you need to use double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what you mean by title here... if it is just what you have in cell A1, then your example is almost there:

```
=$A$1&"-2.0m X 4m (6' 6"" X 13' 1"")"
```

So we have:

- locked the title cell to `$A$1` so that address doesn't change with the
  copy and paste
- used & to do the concatenation
- had to escape the double quotes (inches) in the string

you could have your list of measurements as text in one column and then just use the two cell references joined with & to save headaches!

Comment: Thanks @Stewartside for sorting out my format - it was my first answer!

Comment: No problem. Markdown takes a little while to get used too but it gets easier as it goes along :)